# KonvaJS, masking instead of clipFunc possible?

Tags: javascript, draggable, masking, konvajs

I'm using konvajs and need some help!

Assume that I need an image that's draggable inside a complex shape.

I wonder if it's possible to use masking with Konva.Group instead of clipFunc OR a way to convert a masking image to canvas-clip-path and use it with clipFunc!

Like this: [Masking draggable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjtwv.png)

Comment: have you tried it so far?

Comment: try??? idk how to do or what to try!

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: i tried to masking canvas context by drawing use globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in', that doesn't work inside clipFunc (or at least idk how to get it work)

Answer (score 6):

By default `Konva` supports only simple clip with rectangle shape and clipping with `clipFunc` where you can describe required path.

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/clipping/Clipping_Function.html

In both cases, clipping is defined as canvas paths, and you can't define clip here as an image.

But you can draw directly into the canvas with custom `Konva.Shape`.

```
const girafe = new Image();
girafe.onload = () => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    const image = new Konva.Shape({
    sceneFunc: (ctx) => {
      ctx.drawImage(girafe, 0, 0);      
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    },
    // (!) important
    // for this case you need to define custom hit function
    hitFunc: (ctx) => {
      ctx.rect(0, 0, girafe.width, girafe.height);
      ctx.fillStrokeShape(image);
    },
    draggable: true
  });
  layer.add(image);
  layer.draw();
  };
  img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/kKjW3U4.png";

}
girafe.src = "http://i.imgur.com/fQX2P8S.png";
```

The output will be:

[image: demo output]

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/qahulidube/2/edit?js,output

**Note**: remember to define `hitFunc` because `Konva` hit detection will not work for such `sceneFunc`

Another two demos with other behaviors:

http://jsbin.com/huserozire/1/edit?js,output

http://jsbin.com/hawiricaqu/1/edit