# How to clip several complex Images as Shapes in Konva.js, I just found only one complex Image solution in stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs, konva

hello @[lavrton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512042/lavrton) ,I found a similar problem in stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094648/konvajs-masking-instead-of-clipfunc-possible),  your mentioned solution is a shape, but it can't render  several shapes in the meantime. because the sceneFunc and hitFunc both use the whole canvas context, when I draw the new one, the old one will not show in the correct place, but in the counterpart of the context. How to handle it?

use the snippets below several times to build several nodes containing mask, but it meets the problem above

```
const mask = new Konva.Shape({
      id: KONVA_NODE_ID.MASK,
      x: 0.5 * width * (1 - range),
      y: 0.5 * height * (1 - range),
      width: width * range,
      height: height * range,
      sceneFunc: function (context, shape) {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, shape.width(), shape.height())
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in'
        context.drawImage(backObj, 0, 0, shape.width(), shape.height())
      },
      hitFunc: function (context, shape) {
        context.fillStrokeShape(shape)
      },
    })
group.add(mask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have masking, it is better to do it outside Konva with an external canvas element and then just use that canvas for `Konva.Image`:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = imageObj.width;
canvas.height = imageObj.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0)
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in'
ctx.drawImage(backObj, 0, 0);

const image = new Konva.Image({
  image: canvas
});
```